# POST api/customers/ to register user Prestashop Email Invalid

Tags: php, api, web-services, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

Im trying to register user to my Prestashop store through postman,

I use post mydomain/api/customers,

In body I use raw data like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <customer>
        <passwd>
            testpassword
        </passwd>
        <lastname>
            testlastname
        </lastname>
        <firstname>
            testfirstname
        </firstname>
        <email>
            testemail@mail.com
        </email>
    </customer>
</prestashop>
```

And I have error code that Customer -> Email is not valid,
When I use this xml as a body:

```
<customer>
    <passwd>
        testpassword
    </passwd>
    <lastname>
        testlastname
    </lastname>
    <firstname>
        testfirstname
    </firstname>
    <email>
        testemail@mail.com
    </email>
</customer>
```

I got response that passwd is required, anyone have any idea how do I work with this webservice api?

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong input xml; I am able to create customer with following request body. Make sure to add Prestashop tag as parent tag.

```
<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <customer>
    <passwd>admin@123</passwd>
    <lastname>Doe</lastname>
    <firstname>John</firstname>
    <email>john.doe@yopmail.com</email>
  </customer>
</prestashop>
```